# How to set a Google Marker as a Button?

Tags: android, google-maps

Im completely new on android programing..
its possible to set my markers to buttons?
or set the markers to call a AlertDialog?

if yes, can you show me some example?

thank you!

Protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map);

    try{
        InitilizeMap();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    MarkerOptions ponto1 = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(LatPonto1, LongPonto1)).title("tittle");
    ponto1.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE));
    ponto1.infoWindowAnchor(getTitleColor(), getTaskId());
    googleMap.addMarker(ponto1);




}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answer!
its working now, i forgot the .builder and set the button as a neutral..

```
  googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {  
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker point) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(point.equals(p_tur)){

                showAlertDialog();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    void showAlertDialog(){
       AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getBaseContext()).create();

         alert.setTitle("Location Selected");

            alert.setMessage("This is a message");

           alert.setNeutralButton("Place", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                           "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            alert.show();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use onMarkerClickListener and pop up the alert in that.

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(mOnMarkerClickListener);

OnMarkerClickListener mOnMarkerClickListener = new OnMarkerClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            // create your dialog here.
            return false;
        }
    };
```

mMap is an instance of GoogleMaps.